# postgresql cidr find child blocks

Tags: postgresql, ip, cidr

I'm looking for a way to get direct children networks from cidr blocks stored in postgresql using the builtin cidr type.

Example database

```
CREATE TABLE nets (
    id serial primary key,
    net cidr
);
INSERT INTO nets (net) VALUES 
    ('10.1.0.0/16'),
    ('10.1.0.0/20'),
    ('10.1.1.0/24'),
    ('10.1.1.8/29'),
    ('10.1.1.32/28'),
    ('10.2.15.0/24'),
    ('10.2.15.64/27')
```

The desired query should f.e.

- return 10.1.0.0/20 for searchkey 10.1.0.0/16
- 10.1.1.8/29 and 10.1.1.32/28 for searchkey 10.1.1.0/24

What I came up with is (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2b4b5/1):

```
SELECT
  id,
  net
FROM 
  nets n
WHERE 
  net << '10.1.1.0/24' AND
  '10.1.1.0/24' IN (
    SELECT 
      net 
    FROM
      nets
    WHERE
      net >> n.net
    ORDER BY
      net DESC
    LIMIT 1
  )
ORDER BY 
  net
```

This gives the desired result, but it does not scale. Even with only a few thousand entries in the database this gets terribly slow.

Is there another way to achieve this, without adding an explicit parent/child relationship to the database model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: This is a variant, transformed from the [Nested set model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model), it could be even faster (mainly on 9.4+ with the `inet_ops` GiST index):

```
SELECT c.id, c.net
FROM   nets c
WHERE  c.net << '10.1.1.0/24'
AND    NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT 1
  FROM   nets AS m
  WHERE  c.net << m.net AND m.net << '10.1.1.0/24'
);
```

*Original answer*:

A simple `EXCEPT` should scale better with larger input-sets (it won't calculate a sub-plan for every child network):

```
(SELECT id, net
 FROM   nets
 WHERE  net << '10.1.1.0/24')
EXCEPT
(SELECT c.id, c.net
 FROM   nets p
 JOIN   nets c ON c.net << p.net
 WHERE  p.net << '10.1.1.0/24')
ORDER BY net;
```

**Note**: with smaller input-sets, the `EXCEPT` variant might be even slower than your query.

But to maximize performance (both with this & with your query), you should use some index.

If you have PostgreSQL 9.4+, you should use the new `inet_ops` GiST index:

```
CREATE INDEX nets_inet_net_gist ON nets USING gist (inet(net) inet_ops);
```

Otherwise, you can use the `network_ops` btree index:

```
CREATE INDEX nets_inet_net_btree ON nets USING btree (inet(net) network_ops);
```

While `inet_ops` can directly use the `<<` operator, `network_ops` will transform your expression to something like that:

```
Index Cond: (((net)::inet > '10.1.1.0/24'::inet) AND ((net)::inet <= '10.1.1.255'::inet))
```

Comment: wow thank you for the inputs. I will prepare a larger set of test-data and report back if the new query and indexes help my case.

Comment: your query seems to work only if there are no intermittent blocks. if queried for 10.1.0.0/20 it should return 10.1.1.0/24. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2b4b5/6

Comment: @andrekeller sorry, wrong table selected in the except clause. fixed now.

Comment: Thanks, this makes a huge difference. With a database with about 65k child records this now takes roughly 18 seconds instead of 600. Probably still to slow for my project, so maybe I need to add explicit relationships after all...

Comment: @andrekeller could you check the last query too? also, which PostgreSQL version have you got? I highly recommend the `inet_ops` index on 9.4+.

Comment: are you freaking kidding me?? http://pastebin.com/i9Hz5NF2 and yes I'm on postgres 9.4.1 using the inet_ops index as suggested! WOW, just WOW